# Why Jacoco doesn't calculate other modules coverage?

Tags: maven, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I have project with 3 modules
lets say module a, module b and module c.
i am running jacoco for local test. 
lets say i am running for only a test in module a.
But this test also uses some classes in module b.

after that, in the reports i can see only coverage of module a.
why i couldn't see coverage of module b, however this test uses module b and c.

Answer (score 1):

This is because JaCoCo instrument .class files on the fly. And therefore do that only for your current module and not its dependency. So it reports only the coverage on instrumented files ie the files of your module.